# Script Issues with find -> tar/gzip

Tags: unix, find, gzip, tar

I am currently working on a script, to store/backup our old files, so that we have more space on our server. This script will be used as a cronjob to backup the stuff every week. My script currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentDate=$(date '+%Y%m%d%T' | sed -e 's/://g') 
find /Directory1/ -type f -mtime +90 | xargs tar cvf - | gzip > /Directory2/Backup$currentDate.tar.gz
find /Directory1/ -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;
```

The script is at first saving the current Date + Timestamp(without ":") as a variable. Afterwards it searches for files older than 90 days, tars them and finally makes a gzip out of them, which has the name "Backup$currentDate.tar.gz".
Then it's supposed to find the files again and remove them.

I do however have some issues here:

Directory1 consists of multiple Directories. It does find the files and creates the gz file, but while some files are zipped properly(for instance /DirName1/DirName2/DirName3/File), others appear directly in the "root" Dir. What could be the issue here?

Is there a way to tell the Script, to only create the gz file, if files are found? Because currently, we get gz files, even if there was nothing found, leading to empty directories.

Can I somehow use the find output later on(store variable?), so that the remove at the end really only targets those files found in the step before? Because if the third step would take, let's say a hour and the last step gets executed after it's finished, it could potentially remove files, that weren't older than 90 days before, but are now, so they are never backed up, but then deleted(highly unlikly, but not impossible).

If there's anything else you need to know, feel free to ask ^^

Best regards

Comment: Do you have GNU Tar?  It'll do most of that for you.  https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/

Comment: Sadly I don't and also am not allowed to install it.

Comment: Is this AIX?  What version?
    uname -a

Comment: AIX 7.1(7100-04-01-1543)

Comment: Does no one have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "rephrased" your original code a bit.  I don't have an AIX machine to test anything, so DO NOT cut and paste this.  Using this code, you should be able to address your issues.  To wit:

- It make a record of what files it intends to operate on (`$BFILES`).
- This record can be used to check for empty tar files.
- This record can be used to see why your find is producing "funny" output.  It wouldn't surprise me to find that xargs hit a space character.
- This record can be used to delete exactly the files archived.

As a child, I had a serious accident with xargs and have avoided it ever since.  Maybe there is a safe version out there.

```
#!/bin/bash

# I don't have an AIX machine to test this, so exit immediately until
# someone can proof this code.
exit 1

currentDate=$(date '+%Y%m%d%T' | sed -e 's/://g') 

BFILES=/tmp/Backup$currentDate.files

find /Directory1 -type f -mtime +90 -print > $BFILES
# Here is the time to proofread the file list, $BFILES

# The AIX page I read lists the '-L' option to take filenames from an
# input file.  I've found xargs to be sketchy unless you are very
# careful about quoting.

#tar -c -v -L $BFILES -f - | gzip -9 > /Directory2/Backup$currentDate.tar.gz

# I've found xargs to be sketchy unless you are very careful about
# quoting.  I would rather loop over the input file one well quoted
# line at a time rather than use the faster, less safe xargs.  But
# here it is.

#xargs rm < $BFILES
```